# Are these maximal linear mixed models (within-subject within-item factorial design) really maximal?

Tags: r, mixed-model, repeated-measures, lme4-nlme

What is the **maximal** linear mixed effects model of a 2 x 2 within-subject and
within-item factorial design with multiple observations for each subject-item-factor level combination:
`m1` (as I have seen quite often) but why not `m2` or even `m3`?

```
m1: Y ~ 1 + A*B + (1 + A*B|subject) + (1 + A*B|item)

m2: Y ~ 1 + A*B + (1 + A*B|subject) + (1 + A*B|item) + (1|subject:item)

m3: Y ~ 1 + A*B + (1 + A*B|subject) + (1 + A*B|item) + (1 + A*B|subject:item)
```

I know that these models are often over-parameterized but if one wants to start with the maximal model and try to find an 'optimal' model via reduction, then it should be the correct maximal model in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Models `m2` and `m3` can only be estimated if you have repetitions on the level of the participant-item combination. For `m3` for the full factorial design. Otherwise this random effect is confounded with the residual variance.

In our [recent chapter](http://singmann.org/download/publications/singmann_kellen-introduction-mixed-models.pdf) we wrote the following about this issue (in footnote 6):

> If we had replicates for each combination of participant and item, we
>   could additionally estimate random effects for the random effects
>   grouping factor resulting from the participant-by-item interaction,
>   potentially with random slopes for all fixed effects. With such data,
>   such a model would constitute the maximal model. As the example
>   experiment however did not include this data, this effect is
>   confounded with the residual variance and cannot be estimated.

To sum this up, for this and all other random effect parameter you need more than one data point for each level of the random-effect grouping factor and fixed-effect factor. Otherwise it cannot be estimated. `lme4` will also produce a corresponding error and not estimate such a model.

Comment: Thanks, that's in line with my (limited) understanding. Can you elaborate on the fact that the random effect is confounded with the residual variance otherwise (i.e. what does this mean)?  I could also ask this as a separate question if you think that's a better idea..

Comment: Maybe the following link helps: http://singmann.org/mixed-models-for-anova-designs-with-one-observation-per-unit-of-observation-and-cell-of-the-design/

Comment: You need at least one independent data point to identify each free parameter. In this case you would have one more parameters than data points (the residual variance). Then your model parameters are not identified. In other words, the random effects are confounded with the variance. It is all about counting parameters.

Comment: Does this also apply to continuous covariates? I.e., how many data points are needed to estimate random intercepts and/or random slopes for a continuous covariate?

Comment: This applies exactly in the same manner for continuous covariates. With only one data point you cannot estimate a random slope. Note however that you probably want more than just the necessary number for estimating the continuous random slope in a reasonable manner.

Comment: So the needed number would be 3? In the 'categorical case' one needs two data points per subject to estimate random intercepts. And if the same applies to continuous covariates one would need two data points per subject to estimate random intercepts and one more (?) to estimate random slopes?

Comment: I asked my second Q as a separate question https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/328629/136579